# QGIS 2.8.1 (Windows 64bit). Setting snapping to the "decoration" grid?

Tags: qgis, digitizing, snapping

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to snap digitizing to the grid you can create in View>Decorations>Grid?

I can't see anything in the manual or the menus so I am thinking there probably isn't but it would be really helpful for me if you could so I thought I would ask. I'm not great with python but I'm willing to give it a go if that's what it takes.

Comment: It would be enough to create a linear shapefile with 'vector reticle' and then use the snap on the reticle.

Answer (score 3):

Possible simple workaround: You can create your own vector grid layer and enable snapping on it.

In menu go to *Vector --> Research Tools --> Vector Gird*

or via MMQGIS plugin *MMQGIS --> Create --> Create Grid Layer*